# How do I change language in React Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, react-google-charts

I need to change the language/locale for my Google Charts dashboard. I'm using the package react-google-charts for this project. There is a language parameter in its distribution file:

```
windowGoogleCharts.charts.load(version || "current", {
  packages: packages || ["corechart", "controls"],
  language: language || "en",
  mapsApiKey: mapsApiKey
});
```

filename: index.cjs.js

How can I get to it? To use this package in my projects all they give you is a `<Chart />` component, and I'm assuming the library has been loaded by then.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you ever found the answer, but after looking at the source code and a couple of trials and errors due to the lack of decent documentation, it seems you just need to pass the `chartLanguage` prop.

Something like that:

```
<Chart
    chartType='Calendar'
    data={data}
    options={options}
    chartLanguage={currentLanguage}
  />
```